# Each identity arrow is the corresponding identity function viewed as a monotone map.

Tags: category-theory

I'm studying Category Theory from the book "An Introduction to Category Theory" by Harold Simmons. I found a statement there "Each identity arrow is the corresponding identity function viewed as a monotone map." Can anyone kindly explain it to me what it means? Thanks!

P. S. I am NOT asking about identity function viewed as a morphism, which I have already proven.

Comment: A bit of context might be helpful. What category are you considering? AFAIK Arrows are the same as morphisms.

Comment: @red_trumpet yes, sorry - it seems this statement was written right after the section with presets and posets, so presets would be an appropriate context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the category of posets, the objects are posets (which are just sets with some ordering) and the morphisms are monotone functions. What Simmons wants to say is that a ordinary, set-theoretic, identity map $R\to R$ is a monotone map when $R$ has an ordering, because the reflexivity of a poset. So he says: 'The identity arrow on an object $R$ in the category of posets is the same as the identity arrow on a set $R$ in the category of sets, but now interpreted as a monotone map.' Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I guess since we are only considering reflexivity, the answer works for presets as well.

Comment: Actually, upon thinking again, I am still confused about the above reply. My confusion arises from the fact that if a preset (or a poset) has identity mapping, then we cannot just consider reflexivity to show that it is monotone, isn't it? Can anyone elaborate (dumb it down) this for me again? Thanks.

Comment: A map $f$ between ordered sets is monotone if for all $x$ and $y$, we have that $x\leq y$ then $f(x)\leq f(y)$. Because the identity maps $x$ to $x$ and $y$ to $y$, it is clear that this is indeed a monotone map.

Comment: I understand. Sorry for the confusion, I guess I was overthinking about the nature of the function itself. It seems pretty straightforward. Thanks @EBP